# How to use Alamofires ServerTrustPolicy.disableEvaluation in swift 5 alamofire 5.0.3

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

in alamofire 4 I used this code to disable sever evaluation:

```
private var Manager : Alamofire.Session = {
        // Create the server trust policies
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = ["serverurl.com": .disableEvaluation]
        // Create custom manager
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.Session.defaultHTTPHeaders
        let man = Alamofire.Session(
            configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
        return man
    }()
```

but is not working anymore in alamofire 5 with swift 5 xcode 10.2, I got this errors.

> Use of undeclared type 'ServerTrustPolicy' 
>   Type 'Session' has no member 'defaultHTTPHeaders'

but I cant find a new way to make this work with alamofire 5.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I now have the same problem. @kjoe

Comment: nop, drop alomofire and use NSUrlRequest instead and very happy with it, i think not using AF. any more because of infinity delay

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ServerTrustPolicy` has been replaced with the protocol `ServerTrustEvaluating` in Alamofire 5, and `DisabledEvaluator` has replaced the `.disabled` enum case. To replicate the custom setup you had before:

```swift
private let session: Session = {
    let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["serverurl.com": DisabledEvaluator()])
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default

    return Session(configuration: configuration, serverTrustManager: manager)
}()
```

Comment: BTW, nice idea to increase the points of the stackoverflow:) Just create a wonder lib and change API without documentation:)

Comment: Now i got `Use of unresolved identifier 'URLConfiguration'` using your answer

Comment: @kjoe import Foundation

Comment: Thankyou so much @Jon Shier